# Spring Boot ControllerAdvice TimeoutException Not Caught

Tags: spring, spring-boot, timeoutexception

I have multiple ExceptionHandler in controllerAdvice. one for TimeoutException and other for Exception classes.

When i throw new TimeoutException, it gets caught in Exception Handler not in TimeoutException Handler

below is the code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CoreControllerAdvice {


     @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
     @ResponseBody
     public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(Exception ex) {

        log.info("handleException", ex);
     }

     @ExceptionHandler(value = { TimeoutException.class })
     @ResponseBody
     public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleTimeoutException(Exception ex) {

        log.info("handleTimeoutException", ex);
     }
}
```

I throw Exception as

```
throw new TimeoutException("test");
```

Can some one help, why it is not caught by TimeoutException Handler

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in the method handleTimeoutException seems incorrect to me, instead of **Exception** it should be **TimeoutException**.

```
 @ExceptionHandler(value = { TimeoutException.class })
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleTimeoutException(TimeoutException ex) {

    log.info("handleTimeoutException", ex);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Joydeep, Thanks for responding, i tried with TiemoutException also..